# How to add custom post type admin menu into a group?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I've followed [this](https://tommcfarlin.com/add-a-separator-to-the-wordpress-menu/) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2666/add-a-separator-to-the-admin-menu) article to add a separator to admin menu. Problem is my custom post type `menu_position` is 20(below Pages) if I add update my index to 20 my Menu is removed. I've added bbpress plugin. There `menu_position` is `555555` but it is above the Appearance Page.

[image]

How can I create something like above without messing with menu_position?

Answer (score 2):

Menu position 35 is worked for me, try it

```
$args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'       => 35,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
    );


    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
```

[image]

Comment: @Mifas Please accept this answer if it is helped you.